# How browser protects process memory from webassembly compiled code?

Tags: security, heap-memory, webassembly

According to "Analyzing the Performance of WebAssembly vs. Native Code" research, a webassembly code is compiled into native x86 instructions in Chrome. As far as I understood, it is possible to create WS code which will access random memory in random address.
Of course, there will be segfault if WA tries to access memory which is not belongs into process. But, in the same time, JS and WA runs in the same process, is not it?
How Chrome protects Javascript memory from webassembly? What if WS code will find out address range for internal JS structures and modify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wasm code cannot directly access physical memory, neither inside the Wasm engine itself nor anywhere else in the process. It can only access memory within its declared "linear memory" array, which is like accessing a big byte array.

Out of bounds access to this array does not seg-fault. Instead, the Wasm execution will be aborted with a so-called trap, a kind of exception on the Wasm level. Engines can implement bounds checks in any way they like. On 32 bit architectures it is typically an actual address comparison. On 64 bit architectures, engines can use more efficient virtual memory techniques, which cause a hardware signal that the engine then catches and translates into a trap. However, the hardware fault in this case is an implementation detail and not observable by Wasm code.

Comment: You answered "how it works according to standard". My question is "how it is implemented in browsers". Browser compile WS code into native x86 instructions. How it checks that output asm code will not go out of borders "pre-defined linear memory"? WS code and JS code runs in the same process (thread?), right? At least they should do so because they have shared memory.

So, my question is about "how this trap mechanism in implemented in browsers".

How CPU knows that this part of instructions is able to access only subset of process memory?

Comment: I thought I explain that in the second paragraph? I.e., either by compiling in explicit bounds checks or by intercepting hardware signals.

Comment: I still do not understand. I opened https://mbebenita.github.io/WasmExplorer/, I wrote this code:

```C
char test() {
  char *p = (char *)(0x0);
  return p[0xAABBCC];
};
```

Complied asm output contains this line `movsx eax, byte ptr [r15 + 0xaabbcc]`.
Does `r15` makes this "more efficient virtual memory techniques"?

Am I right that on x64 architecture browsers uses some 4gb memory range which holds only WS ASM data?

Comment: Yes, r15 points to the base address of the memory's backing store, which is an 8 GiB address range, the beginning of which is the memory at its current size and the rest an unmapped red zone accessing which will signal a memory fault that the engine catches. (It has to be 8GiB because Wasm's memory instructions use an 32 bit index plus a 32 bit offset.)

Answer (score 1):

WebAssembly is not able to address directly into any process memory, rather, it is only allowed to read / write to memory addresses within the pre-defined ‘linear memory’, which webassembly modules share with their JavaScript host.

So no, WebAssembly can not access random memory at a random address.